# MKAnnotation vs MKOverlay; centering crosshairs

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

Newbie best practices question here; I'll write the code if someone can give me a gentle push in the right direction...

On my MKMapView, I would like a cross-hairs or some other indication of where the center of the map is as the user scrolls and zooms.  Should this best be achieved as an annotation I keep removing and adding, or as an overlay that I keep resizing and repositioning?  Or a third solution?  The goal here is best user experience...

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by center of the map? The center of the world or the center of the screen? If it's at a fixed location on the world, use an annotation. If it is fixed on screen set up a UIView that hovers over your MKMapview and passes any touch events through to the views below

Comment: [OP] I mean the center of the MKMapView, regardless of the region displayed.  Is that the preferred/simplest method, to pass touches through a UIView?

Comment: Well I haven't done a survey of other users but every time I've tried to counteract the movement of something to keep an inner object in the same place on screen it ends up being simpler to take it out of the moving thing.